# Native product commenting system for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2

I have not been able to find a `native` commenting system for Magento 2.

I am in the need of a commenting system that is "`not`" working based on Disqus, Facebook or any third party website, but runs on the shop's server.

Users should be able to `comment on each product's page` and the commenting system can be moderated through the Magento admin panel. Is there a Magento Module that offers such functionality?

As an example, please look at the attached screenshot. It explains that I am not looking for a reviewing system that we already have in Magento, but instead, I am looking for something more like what we get when we install a Disqus or Facebook comment module on Magentto. So if a Disqus comment is added (for example) then users can use their Disqus ID to add a comment on a product's page. I need that sort of commenting but without being connected to a third party website, I want users to use their own name, and info stored in their account, in the store. I hope it makes sense and if not, please let me know and I will explain more.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

--

[image: Sample of how the Ask a Question part looks like in the Magento Marketplace.]

Comment: what type of feature you want in that module ?

Comment: Nothing really fancy, something very simple that allows logged-in users to comment on each product's page, and can be moderated through the Magento admin panel. So they will not have to use their third-party identity to comment on products but the very own user name that they have on the shop itself. Let's say something like this very comment that I placed here, I did not have to login to facebook, I can edit it here, very simple.

Comment: i tried to post an answer below , is that you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 default Review system:

To open all reviews:

[image: Magento Review rating]

To manage reviews :
[image: How to manage review in magento 2]

If you are looking for some extra info from users you can search marketplace:

1) https://marketplace.magento.com/feefo-reviews.html

2) [Extension related to Reviews for Magento 2](https://marketplace.magento.com/extensions.html#q=review&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%202&hFR%5Bcategories.level0%5D%5B0%5D=Extensions&nR%5Bvisibility_catalog%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1)

Comment: I am not really looking for a reviewing system, I have searched the Magento Marketplace already, and unfortunately, there is nothing quite like what I need. To make it easier to understand I added a photo to the comment.

Comment: @Ogdila Ok i understood you want a `Disqus` type feature where user can ask share something related to that product than someone or any moderator or any other user can reply on the same. If yes, unfortunately, i didn't found the same. but it can be achieved, for this we have to create a custom module

Comment: @Ogdila and i like your requirement, one more question why don't you want to integrate `Disqus`  ?

Comment: I am trying to stay away from embeddable services to provide a more genuine feeling to the customers. Also, it provides a piece of mind for the customers to be sure their comments will be using their store identity, and will not to be shared in other platforms in any way. There are usability tests showing that users feel more attached when they have a feeling of communicating in a closed platform and may spend more time to be involved.